# variable "x" in block "square" must be assigned a default value

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I am using Emacs 24/Org 7.8 and am having some issues with org-babel.  I want to call a block of code with #+call:

```
#+name: square(x)
#+begin_src python
return x*x
#+end_src
#+call: square(x=6)
```

Evaluating #+call with C-c C-c gives the message:

> variable "x" in block "square" must be assigned a default value

Any advice on how to debug this?  I have the following code related org-babel in my init.el:

```lisp
(org-babel-do-load-languages
     'org-babel-load-languages
     '((R . t)
       (python . t)
       (js . t)
       (scheme . t)
       (C . t)
       (lilypond . t)
       (maxima . t)
       (octave . t)))
```

Adding `:var x=1` to the `begin_src` line like so:

```
#+name: square(x)
#+begin_src python :var x=1
return x*x
#+end_src
#+call: square(x=6)
```

don't stop me from receiving the error.

Investigating with the emacs debugger, I find that `ref` isn't holding `"x=6"`, but is instead holding `"x"`.

```lisp
 (org-babel-merge-params
             (mapcar
              (lambda (ref) (cons :var ref))
              (mapcar
               (lambda (var) ;; check that each variable is initialized
         (if (string-match ".+=.+" var)
                 var
               (error
                "variable \"%s\"%s must be assigned a default value"
                var (if name (format " in block \"%s\"" name) ""))))
               (org-babel-ref-split-args (match-string 5))))
             (nth 2 info))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treating your questions as two parts (issue with variable X and issue with emacs-lisp).

Emacs-Lisp

I would suggest making sure you include `(emacs-lisp . t)` in your list of `org-babel-load-languages`.  That should resolve the issue with it not finding emacs-lisp.  You can also try `M-: (require 'ob-emacs-lisp)` and your issue should be resolved (it forces it to load the emacs-lisp babel code).

Variable Issue

I had to do a few tests to figure out exactly where the issue was, it turns out there's two ways to declare variables when trying to run Org Babel blocks.  I'm using emacs-lisp for the test because I don't have a python interpreter installed at the moment, but the results should be equivalent.  The error message is telling you that you must by default declare a value for your variable `(x=1)`.  Once you do that your code blocks should be fine.

```
* Declare variable in name
#+name: square(x=1)
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (* x x)
#+end_src

#+results: square
: 1

#+call: square(x=45)

#+results: square(x=45)
: 2025

#+call: square(5)

#+results: square(5)
: 25

* Declare variable in begin_src
#+name: square2
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var x=1
  (* x x)
#+end_src

#+results: square2
: 1

#+call: square2(5)

#+results: square2(5)
: 25

#+call: square2(x=45)

#+results: square2(x=45)
: 2025
```

Comment: I know this is how its supposed to work, but my `org-babel-get-src-block-info` function in `ob.el` is returning the error because `var` (a global variable that presuably should hold the list of ".+=.+" strings only holds `"x"` despite using the same org syntax as you.

Comment: No, it is failing because you have `square(x)`.  The first half of my example shows the syntax for that.  You need it to be `square(x=1)` for var to have a default value.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I was too sure I had ruled out what you wrote. I will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** The code below works for versions of `org-mode` before 7.8.  To get this working with 7.8 and beyond, you should use `#+name` instead of `#+srcname`.

The two things you list aren't necessarily related.

For the python bit, you should use `srcname` instead of `name`.  You also need to let the block know that there is an input variable, by specifying the `:var` header argument.  You should also define a default variable here, otherwise python would complain.  This is actually misleading in the current online documentation.  You want something like:

```
#+srcname: square
#+begin_src python :var x=1
  return x*x
#+end_src
```

Upon evaluating `#+call: square(x=6)` with `C-c C-c` gives:

```
#+results: square(x=6)
: 36
```

The second issue seems to be related to your `org-babel-load-languages` variable.  By default, the `emacs-lisp` language should be loaded.  Are you perhaps changing this in your *.emacs* file?  Your above lisp code works fine for me, and I have the following in my *.emacs*:

```lisp
; org-babel stuff
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((org . t)
   (emacs-lisp . t)
   (gnuplot . t)
   (python . t)
   (octave . t)
   (latex . t)
   (perl . t)
   (sh . t)
   (ditaa . t)))
(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)
(require 'org-exp-blocks)
```

but the `(emacs-lisp . t)` line shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Actually as of `7.8` the proper use is `#+name:` as opposed to `#+srcname:`

Comment: Like Jon said, I am using Org-mode 7.8.  This information has been added to the question.

Comment: Actually, your syntax adapted for 7.8 worked just as well.  Thanks very much!

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin Ah, good point.  I had seen there were changes to src block names in the mailing list, but didn't see the final consensus.